# How do I load up Google Collections Library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, guava

I'm currently trying to learn to use Guava so I downloaded the source by doing this:

```
svn checkout http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ guava-libraries-read-only
```

Sorry if this sounds really stupid but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to load up the source in Eclipse to examine it. I've tried different ways (creating, importing, etc) but always end up with package problems.

I'm using Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu by the way.

Can I get some help on this? Thanks!

EDIT: I'm trying to examine the source so I would like to add the source as a project.

Comment: Are you trying to load it as a project so you can look through the code or just to link the sources so you can jump to the source files when you're using the library?

Comment: Can you specify the errors you are seeing?

Comment: @ColinD I'm trying to load it as a project so I can examine the source.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do...

1. Go to the [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/list) and grab the latest bundled release
2. Unzip it to some local directory
3. Copy the `guava-r<version>.jar` to your project's lib directory.
4. Right click on the JAR from Eclipse and say "Add to Build Path".

If you need the source you can attach the `guava-r<version>-src.jar` in Eclipse via the *Configure Build Path* project menu or by using the *attach source* button during debug.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to [download a Jar from the Guava site](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=guava-r08.zip), copy it into your Eclipse project and add it to the build path using the *jar context menu > Build Path > Add to Build Path*. Also, point Eclipse to the included source zip using *project context menu > Configure Build Path...* to get Javadoc on the Guava classes.

Comment: I think he wants to peek at the source, not use the library. Though Guava is not developed in Eclipse. there's a pom.xml, so possibly maven could be used to generate eclipse project files

Comment: @nos With the setup I described the sources are available. Also the questions starts with 'I'm currently trying to learn to use Guava' - I think this is the easiest way to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it two ways: the [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and [Maven](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) eclipse plugins.  Both offer "create project from repository"-like options.  Both plugins have reasonable online help, so I'll not repeat exact steps here.

Creating a project from the repositories will give you a full view of the source (and documentation, build files, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late in answering ... but you could also simply install the guava bundle from the update site "[guava-bundle](http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/guava-bundle/trunk/repository/)"; it will install the sources along and you'll then just have to import the plugins in your workspace (File > Import > plugins and fragment... don't forget to tick the "projects with source folder" checkbox on the first page of this wizard) and browse the source from it.

Note that this update site has now been discontinued in profit of [Guava-osgi](http://code.google.com/p/guava-osgi/) which also provide an update site for easy installation ... but I haven't installed it yet and thus don't know whether the sources are included in the artifacts installed through this update site.